# Problem with moving a winform using C#

Tags: c#, winforms

My form doesn't have a title bar, so I am implementing the code to drag
the entire form around the screen. I am using the below code to do it, which works fine.
I have two panels in my form, `PanelA` and `PanelB`. During the startup I show
`PanelA` where the dragging works perfectly. Later when the user clicks
the button in `PanelA`, I need to make `PanelA` invisible and show `PanelB`
However, the dragging does not work when `PanelB` is shown. What's the 
problem here?

```
private void SerialPortScanner_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    this.drag = false; 
}

private void SerialPortScanner_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    this.drag = true;
    this.start_point = new Point(e.X, e.Y);
}

private void SerialPortScanner_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (this.drag)
    {
        Point p1 = new Point(e.X, e.Y);
        Point p2 = this.PointToScreen(p1);
        Point p3 = new Point(p2.X - this.start_point.X,
                             p2.Y - this.start_point.Y);
        this.Location = p3;
    }
}
```

Comment: You've to be a bit clear. What is SerialPortScanner? Which mouseevent initiate these methods? Is it from PanelA or PanelB or Form? If these are PanelA events, then you've to handle the PanelB events also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:** I've realized that you're not asking about *drag and drop*, but rather about moving your form around the screen. (Thanks to @Veer.)  I've edited your question to help clarify this.  Drag and drop is a completely different thing, since it is dragging information from one control to another.

The same principle of my answer still applies though, since mouse events are also handled at the Control level - you might need to handle the mouse events from `PanelB` as well.

Comment: Handling the drag and drop events are for the forms Right ?
Is there anything like, i need to handle from panel also ??

Comment: @karthik: Drag and Drop is at the Control level (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.dragdrop%28VS.80%29.aspx).  If you want to have drag and drop within `PanelB`, then you will need to handle it there also.

Comment: Your reference http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.dragdrop%28VS.80%29.aspx deals with DragDrop event. But i don't think any such event is used by the QA. He just wants to manually drag his window.

Comment: @Veer: Oh, yes, that looks like that is what the OP wants, now that I read the question in that light.  Drag *and drop* is what threw me off...